# Does the JMS API support asynchronous bidirectional messaging?

Tags: java, jms

The examples I have seen seem to support several use cases:

1. Point to point - single publisher to single consumer, unidirectional communication from publisher to consumer
2. Publish/subscribe - publisher to multiple consumers, unidirectional communication from publisher to consumer
3. Request/response - single publisher to single consumer, bidirectional communication but blocking

What I'm looking for is bidirectional asynchronous messaging. For example I would like to do the following

```
Publisher: "Hello world" to consumer
Consumer: Process "Hello world"

Wait 5 minutes

Consumer: "Hello publisher" to publisher
Publisher: Process "Hello publisher"
```

Does the API support the above use case? Or would I need to implement everything as publisher and consumer concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your best bet is to use 2 queues.  The same object on each side can be a producer on one queue and a consumer on the other.  Then you have:

```
Object1 "Hello world" -> queueDirection1 ->  Object2 processes "hello world" 
Object2 "Hello world" -> queueDirection2 ->  Object1 processes "hello world"
```

This is now completely asynchronous, with no timing requirements between the queues.

I think that any configuration with a single queue or a single topic presents a risk of undesired blocking, or perhaps self-receiving a message.  Be sure to consider how the system will behave if the message rate increases, or the processing time increases.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but an implementation that uses `JMSReplyTo` might be a way to go about this.

Check this [How should I implement request response with JMS?](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) doc from ActiveMQ

Comment: In this case will it use the same queue? I thought JMS queues are unidirectional...

Answer (score 0):

JMS does not have any API for your requirement. You can implement your requirement using  point to point messaging.

Publisher "Hello World" -> Q1 -> Consumer processes "Hello World".

Wait 5 seconds

Consumer says "Hello World" -> Q1 -> Publisher processes "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Camel http://camel.apache.org/ and work with JMS component to send a message in In/InOut way. Camel creates a temporary queue to send an answer back for every request if you use inOut way.
Also it provides a lot possibilities for varied message processing and message content enrichment on-fly.

Comment: Camel creates a temporary queue to send an answer back. When timeout elapsed Camel throws RequestTimeoutException if an answer isn't received.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with websocket (SockJS) . In every message from client can add the client Id. Sending it to server , the message broker will redirect it back to all clients (/topic) and by client Id will distinguish the sender .